# How to Update data in DataGrid

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am trying to update my DataGrid but unfortunately not able to! My application have a DataGrid to which data is loaded from a CSV file. Some of the data needs to get updated. But I am not able to find the right way to reflect the updates on the grid.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Creation of my DataGrid
this.dataSource = new DataSet();
DataTable data = new DataTable("Products");    


data.Columns.Add("Note", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
data.Columns.Add("Details", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
data.Columns.Add("Net", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
data.Columns.Add("Empty Weight", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
data.Columns.Add("Full Weight", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
data.Columns.Add("Description", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
data.Columns.Add("UOM", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
data.Columns.Add("Item", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

dataSource.Tables.Add(data);
dataGrid1.DataSource = data;
```

When User press a "Load" button, I load the data to my grid:

```
DataTable vehicle = dataSource.Tables[0];
.
. // data is read from CSV
.
vehicle.Rows.Add("A sample note", "...", full - empty, empty, full, "Test description", "Gr", i); // an example
```

Here is how I tried to update the data on the grid:

```
DataTable vehicle = dataSource.Tables[0];
vehicle.Rows[0].BeginEdit();
vehicle.Rows[0].ItemArray[0] = "TEST COMPLETE";            
vehicle.Rows[0].EndEdit();
vehicle.AcceptChanges();
dataGrid1.Update();
```

But there is no update to the grid.. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developers facing the same issue, here is how I fixed mine:

You can make use of the SetField method to update the data in the Grid's row. Assuming that you have the row index to modify in variable `currentRow`, there is how I modified my data:

```
DataTable vehicle = dataSource.Tables[0];
vehicle.Rows[this.currentRow].SetField(4, "Updating the 5th column in the grid");
vehicle.Rows[this.currentRow].SetField(2, "Updating the 3rd column in the grid");
```

If you need to remove the row from the grid, you can make use of the `RemoveAt` method:

```
dataGridTable.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndexToDelete);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never gotten tools like `Update` or `AcceptChanges` to work the way I want them to. I suspect they do something different than what seems obvious to me.

Also, I have no knowledge if a separate DataTable is linked (i.e. via an underlying pointer). Making a change to the DataTable may or may not translate to changing the data stored in the DataGridView.

For me, I reassign it.

```
private void UpdateTheDataGrid() {
  DataTable vehicle = (DataTable)dataGrid1.DataSource;
  // vehicle.Rows[0].BeginEdit(); <- Unsure if this is even needed
  vehicle.Rows[0].ItemArray[0] = "TEST COMPLETE";            
  // vehicle.Rows[0].EndEdit();
  vehicle.AcceptChanges();
  dataGrid1.DataSource = vehicle;
}
```

Another technique would be to work directly with the DataGridView control itself:

```
private void UpdateTheDataGrid() {
  dataGrid1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "TEST COMPLETE";
}
```

NOTE to Above: I do not have VS running, so I'm not sure if that code is 100% accurate, but it should give you the idea.

As a comment, I am interested to know if there is any difference between your version of adding a column and the version I use:

```
// Yours
data.Columns.Add("Note", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

// Mine
data.Columns.Add("Note", typeof(string));
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointers.. I fixed the issue in slightly different way.

Comment: Huh... not even a +1 for my time.